# How to type Ŭ (U with breve)?

Tags: compose-key

Esperanto uses the letter Ŭ. <kbd>Compose</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd> = ă, but <kbd>Compose</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>, <kbd>u</kbd> = u.

How do I type this with the compose key? If that is not possible, what is the next easiest way to type it?

Comment: See this question and its answers on [esperanto.se]: https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/q/378/7

Comment: Note that their solution of compse, shift + 9, u does not work on my keyboard. However, compose, u, u does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depends on the version of X11 (<strike>assuming you are not using</strike>  or wayland) and keyboard layout, but generally <kbd>Compose</kbd>, <kbd>b</kbd>, <kbd>u</kbd> or <kbd>Compose</kbd>, <kbd>u</kbd>, <kbd>u</kbd> should work (IIRC <kbd>Compose</kbd>, <kbd>(</kbd> was used for breve some (long) time ago).

See also `/usr/share/X11/locale/*/Compose`.

Comment: @marcelm thanks, edited (and I meant `u` `U` anyway as the latter option)

Comment: I didn't realize I was only looking at an abbreviated table until now. Here is a complete list of compose keys in xlib: https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/libX11/i18n/compose/en_US.UTF-8.html

Answer (score 3):

Ŭ or ŭ is a letter in the Esperanto alphabet, based on u with breve.

Press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> keyboard combination which will print a `u` character on the screen. Then after the `u` type one of the 4-digit hexadecimal codes in the second column and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to render the u+4-digit hexadecimal number that appears on the screen as the appropriate u with breve character.

| Character | Hex | HTML Entity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ŭ | 016c | &#364; |
| ŭ | 016d | &#365; |