# Can't type accented letters in certain programs

Tags: keyboard, input-devices

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 last week and haven't been able to type accents in some programs.

For programs like Chrome, Terminal and the native folders it's working as intended (eg typing `´` followed by `a` gives you `á`, `~` followed by `a` gives you `ã`, etc).

But for programs like Firefox, Discord and Spotify typing `´` followed by `a` will either give you a regular `a` or no letter at all. Same goes for the other accents.

Any ideas?

Edit: I use a pt-br keyboard layout

Edit 2: Finally got it to work. Keyboard input method was set to XIM and switching it to iBus fixed it

Comment: Provide information on the keyboard layout you use. I cannot reproduce that in Firefox with a US International keyboard layout.

Comment: Looks like a problem I had: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1425841/wrong-setting-for-my-belgian-keyboard-at-logon-after-upgrade-to-22-04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to type Ŭ (U with breve)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1432849/how-to-type-%c5%ac-u-with-breve)

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar issue with my 22.04 instance using an English (UK) keyboard as the Input Source it having previously worked fine in my 20.04 instance with similar keyboard selected.

In `Settings > Keyboard` I changed the `Compose Key` to `Right Ctrl` to test it and the functionality issue being experienced was fixed.

So <kbd>Right CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> (pressed individually in sequence) again produces ç etc.

Answer (score 0):

I already had @graham's setting made but still found issues using certain web apps like forums.

For example, the [Sublime Text forum](https://forum.sublimetext.com/) does not give you the right character for a cedille when you type a 9 on a French keyboard.

A similar miscoding occurs on a [financial matters forum](https://www.askaboutmoney.com).

When some member of these forums has a user name which contains an accented character, I see a Cyrillic character instead when viewing the site on my PC - but I observe the correct character when viewing it on my Android phone !

Others report the same thing.

This tends to rule out absence of sufficient languages/keyboards on the web app's server as the cause and suggests some misconfiguration on the client machine . . .

Weirdest of all is the fact that my admin account has everything displaying properly on the affected forums - yet when I look at language and keyboard settings, they are the same as on the user account where the issue is observed . . .

## EDIT

I unchecked the option to *Allow pages to choose their own fonts ...* in the Firefox settings:

[image]

The rendered font changes to the default DegaVu and the accent characters return.